Overloading method for accepting tuple and variadic, both const ref and move
I have a class, which receives a lambda in constructor and is supposed to run the lambda on worker threads. I want to pass arguments for the runs to its queue, but of course to store them before execution, they need to be in a tuple.
I want to mostly be able to add arguments as variadics, both as const reference and move semantics, but if they need to be saved as tuples then there is no reason not to allow passing the ready tuples too...
This is what I currently have:
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>  // pair
#include <tuple>
#include <future>


template<class Ret, class... Args>
class Executor
{
public:
    using ArgTpl = std::tuple<Args...>;

    using Function = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
    typedef Ret(*FunctionPtr)(Args...);

private:
    using Future = std::future<Ret>;
    using Promise = std::promise<Ret>;

    using Task = std::pair<Promise, ArgTpl>;

    const Function callback;
    std::queue<Task> task_queue;

public:
    Executor(Function f) : callback(f) {}
    Executor(FunctionPtr fp) : Executor(static_cast<Function>(fp)) {}

    ~Executor() {}

    //

    Future push(const Args&... args)// requires (sizeof...(args) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Args&..." << endl;
        return push(std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
    }

    Future push(Args&&... args)// requires (sizeof...(args) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Args&&..." << endl;
        return push(std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
    }

    Future push(const ArgTpl& args)
    {
        cout << "ArgTpl&" << endl;
        ArgTpl a = args;
        return push(std::move(a));
    }

    Future push(ArgTpl&& args)
    {
        cout << "ArgTpl&&" << endl;
        Promise p;
        Future f = p.get_future();
        task_queue.emplace(std::make_pair(std::move(p), std::move(args)));
        return f;
    }
};

int func()
{
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    //*/
    {
        std::function lbd = []() -> int { return 1; };

        //Executor thrdmgr(lbd);
        Executor thrdmgr(func);

        //cout << "1st:" << endl;
        //thrdmgr.push();
        //cout << "2nd:" << endl;
        //thrdmgr.push(); // ???
        cout << "3rd:" << endl;
        std::tuple<> t;
        thrdmgr.push(t);
        cout << "4th:" << endl;
        thrdmgr.push(std::move(t));
    }
    /*/
    {
        std::function lbd = [](const std::string& str) -> void { cout << "Hello: " << str << endl; };

        Executor thrdmgr(lbd);

        //cout << "1st:" << endl;
        //const std::string s1 = "strref";
        //thrdmgr.push(s1);
        //cout << "2nd:" << endl;
        //std::string s2 = "strmove";
        //thrdmgr.push(std::move(s2));
        cout << "3rd:" << endl;
        const std::tuple<std::string> t {"tuple"};
        thrdmgr.push(t);
        cout << "4th:" << endl;
        thrdmgr.push(std::move(t));
    }
    //*/

    system("pause");
}

It compiles and works, but I am not sure if I am using the proper move/forwarding/etc everywhere.
However I'm not even able to call all of the overloads, so maybe this whole endeavor is pointless... I thought that only for void arg, the first two overloads will be the same and I tried adding the requires (sizeof...(args) != 0) but it's the same even for the string example.
The const Args&... and Args&&... are too similar and I'm getting member function already defined or declared. That's why in the main the 1st and 2nd are commented out.
How should it be done properly? Or maybe some of these overloads are unnecessary?

How do these free push overloads have access to task_queue?

@TedLyngmo they are members, inside the class. Will edit for clarification.

Ok, but it still doesn't compile and work. Please provide a [mre].

@TedLyngmo Why do you even need an example, when I am asking about theory?
But fine, I will make one, as soon as I fix the template that stopped working for whatever reason...

It's easier to just copy & compile your code than to have to fill in the blanks and guess what the missing parts look like and how you are using it. When you create the MRE, please also include a usage example.

@TedLyngmo added a (semi)working example.

It seems I missed to follow up on this. Would this be what you need?
